# Simplify a radical expression for a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm supposed to find the slope of the tangent of the function $$D(p)=\frac{20}{\sqrt{p-1}}$$ at $p=5$.

Using the definition of slope of a tangent at a point, I get

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{20}{\sqrt{(5+h)-1}}-10}{h}$$

Which, using "regular" (high school) algebra I simplified to $$\frac{10(2-\sqrt{h+4})}{h\sqrt{h+4}}.$$

Rationalizing the numerator or denominator doesn't help in terms of removing $h$ as a factor in the denominator of the slope. How do you find the limit algebraically in this case (or can you)?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by the conjugate, we obtain:
$$ \begin{align*}
\dfrac{10(2-\sqrt{h+4})}{h\sqrt{h+4}}
&=\dfrac{10(2-\sqrt{h+4})}{h\sqrt{h+4}} \cdot \dfrac{2+\sqrt{h+4}}{2+\sqrt{h+4}}\\
&=\dfrac{10(4-(h+4))}{h\sqrt{h+4}(2+\sqrt{h+4})}\\
&=\dfrac{-10h}{h\sqrt{h+4}(2+\sqrt{h+4})}\\
&=\dfrac{-10}{\sqrt{h+4}(2+\sqrt{h+4})}\\
\end{align*} $$
So taking the limit as $h\to0$ yields:
$$
\dfrac{-10}{\sqrt{0+4}(2+\sqrt{0+4})}=\dfrac{-10}{2(2+2)}=\dfrac{-5}{4}
$$

Comment: This is the correct answer - but why nobody here is calculating the derivative of the function? It's the most straightforward way to compute the slope of the tangent at a point (and since differentiability is not excluded one has every right to assume it).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I'm assuming that the OP hasn't yet covered the usual derivative rules (such as $\dfrac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$) and is being asked to use the definition of a derivative using limits.

Comment: Commendable. We tend to forget the technology we don't use anymore, that's true!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use:
$$m=f'(5)=\lim_{p\to 5}\frac{f(p)-f(5)}{p-5}$$ Indeed, you have $$\begin{align} m& =\lim_{p\to 5}\frac{\frac{20}{\sqrt{p-1}}-10}{p-5}\\ \\& =\lim_{p\to 5}\frac{20-10\sqrt{p-1}}{\sqrt{p-1}(p-5)}\\ \\&=\lim_{p\to 5}\frac{-100(p-5)}{\sqrt{p-1}(p-5)(20+10\sqrt{p-1})}\\ \\&=-5/4\end{align}$$